# Wordpress Page editor and products page not displaying correctly

Tags: wordpress

[display issue page edit wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf3rp.png)

I have already done the following and have not resolved the issue:

Deactivate all plugins. Yes... ALL plugins.
Switch to the default twenty theme.
Manually empty and refresh your browser cache

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Gavin, welcome to Superuser. I think it would be helpful if you could add a lot more detail - versions, screenshots, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Did you also flush dns cache to be sure it's still not fixed? I'll also bring a site up in my tablet on my cell network just to be 100% if i believe what I did should have corrected the issue.

Were you using a theme that includes a custom editor? If you were contact their support.
Had you been using the new editor or the legacy editor? If old editor make sure that you download and install the plugin for the legacy editor so it can work in WP versions >5.0. If new editor make sure you no longer have the gutenberg plugin from prior to the 5.0 update.

All else fails, try this:

Next step imo is make sure you backup everything files & database.
Make sure core, themes and plugins are all up to date.
Re upload a fresh version of wordpress admin directory via FTP...
see if that works..

Lastly, delete and install fresh WP from scratch, complete the install then upload wp-config.php and the uploads directory from your backups and see if you're golden..